# opa: google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, opa

I'd like to add a tracker for google analytics in my opa application. I need to put the script provided by google just before the closing  of my html code.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert at the end of your main page :

```
  <script>{
    Xhtml.of_string_unsafe("
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() \{
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
    ")
  }</script>
```

N.B : Notice that you must escape `{` inside the script : `\{`